# URL in web api and angularjs

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

in visual studio 2013 i have setup a web api project and added an index.html page with angularjs framework: why, when i run the project, the url is

```
http://localhost:49375/index.html#/
```

How can i remove the index.hmtl# for the root page?

In angularjs i have the following route:

```
gestionale.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'View/people.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
   });
}]);
```

and in the WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you refer to:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

It is use something like this:

```
angular.module('demoApp',['ngRoute'],function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider.
        when('/',{
...
```

It basically lets you use angular routing without the `#` prefix character.

Comment: he also needs to setup some «match all» server-side route pointing to the bootstraping view or use IIS UrlRewrite...otherwise he'll be disappointed when he starts getting 404 errors :)